# Installed a nvidia driver and broke ubuntu, how would I fix this?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

Right this is pretty much my own fault, I was trying to get steam to work and I had already tried all the experimental drivers so I decided to start from the beginning; I installed the first nvidia driver from the additional drivers menu. Ubuntu does not load.

If I launch from recovery mode the computer tells me that the drivers will not load until I reboot, and I get to log in through what appears to be a full screen terminal. I can ctrl-alt-f1 and ctrl-alt-f2 through and create different log ins.

I was wondering if someone could guide me through the process of uninstalling and installing a working driver from here, that is only IF that is the problem and I missed something completely.

I am running 12.04 on a acer aspire 6935 laptop, if more information is needed please ask away.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Login in one of those terminals
- Issue `dpkg --get-selections | grep nvidia`: you should get there the name of the package providing nVidia driver. It should be something like `nvidia-current`, `nvidia-experimental`, etc.
- Remove it using `sudo apt-get remove <package-name>`

Now reboot and check if it works again. If not try to move xorg.conf:

```
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
```

Comment: Thank you I tried the first three bullet points then, typed sudo reboot, twice I think there were some stuff the computer wanted to do first and it WORKED. I am now running Ubuntu normally on what appears to be the driver I was running before thank you.

Answer (score 0):

press ctrl-alt-f1 and log in to the command line
run "dpkg -l | grep nvidia" to find the package name of the driver
run "sudo apt-get remove YOURDRIVER" (replace with the name of your driver)
run "sudo reboot" you should be back to the stock driver

Comment: I am sorry that I did not get to read your comment before trying the above answer. The answers appear to be the same, and I would to inform you that it worked so thank you!